# asp.net core 2.2 upgrade and HttpSessionState is not available in class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

As I inherited a project that I need to upgrade to .net core 2.2 I'm having issues with several dependencies.

Here I get missing `HttpSessionState`

```
private static string CollectionToHtmlTable(HttpSessionState collection)
    {
        // Converts HttpSessionState to NameValueCollection
        var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach (string item in collection)
        {
            nvc.Add(item, collection[item].ToString());
        }

        return CollectionToHtmlTable(nvc);
    }
```

What are some good code samples of how I can access `HttpSessionState` in a .net core class library?

Comment: I'm not a fan of using these objects outside of the projects/dlls that use them.  To avoid problems like this, you should use the adapter pattern.

Comment: ASP.NET Core has a different way of looking at session state. I don't even know if one can enumerate all things in session state like this. Have a look at https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-session-storage-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: If you get "missing `HttpSessionState`" there, then that means whatever method called this didn't pass the parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` package, which is included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage, provides middleware for managing session state. 
To enable the session middleware,Startup must contain:

1. Any of the IDistributedCache memory caches. The IDistributedCache implementation is used as a backing store for session.
2. A call to `AddSession` in `ConfigureServices`.
3. A call to `UseSession` in `Configure`.

**Code:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseHttpContextItemsMiddleware();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

`HttpContext.Session` is available after session state is configured.

`HttpContext.Session` can't be accessed before `UseSession` has been called.

`InvalidOperationException` exception occurs when `UseSession` is invoked after `UseMvc`.

Session state is accessed from a Razor Pages PageModel class or MVC Controller class with `HttpContext.Session`. This property is an `ISession` implementation.

The `ISession` implementation provides several extension methods to set and retreive integer and string values. The extension methods are in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace (add a

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

statement to gain access to the extension methods)
when the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` package is referenced by the project.

**Access Httpcontext in Class Library:**

`HttpContext` is available  in controllers but to access it other classes you need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in your class.
To access Session use below code:-

```
var sessionValue =_context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("KeyName");
```

More details can be found at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I'm in another project - thus "class libraries"

Comment: @Chad Jacobs : HttpContext is available  in controllers but to access it in other classes you need to inject IHttpContextAccessor in your class.