# How to get session in asp .net core 2.1 when i have .AspNetCore.Session cookie?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

i'm trying to get session by .AspNetCore.Session in a .net core 2.1 project, is there any way to do this ?

Comment: To improve your chances of getting an answer i suggest that you take a look at [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help you get the help you seek much faster.

Comment: Question is already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917697/asp-net-core-2-2-upgrade-and-httpsessionstate-is-not-available-in-class-librarie/53918956#53918956

Comment: What is the meaning of "session id" you mentioned in the comments below? Is it the key parameter of the key-value in the session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a session using an ID. It actually servers responsibility to create session and manage it.
Session Id is just a unique id that server passes it browser to uniquely identify an HttpSession and maintain a conversational State.
Why actually you need to do this. If you think properly then you will not need to create session using an id. There must be another solution for your requirememt. Share your exact requirement so that we might help you.

Answer (score 2):

In Configure Services

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});
```

In Configure before UseMvc()

```
  app.UseSession();
```

Then In Controller,

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Doctor");
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionKeyAge, 773);

var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
var age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyAge);
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

---

**Edit: OP asks how can I get session id?**

Inside Controller you can use

```
HttpContext.Session.Id
```

Out of Controller you need to use IHttpContextAccessor

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly HttpContext context;

    public RequestInformation(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) 
    {
        this.context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public string GetSettionId()
    {
        return HttpContext.Session.Id;
    }
}
```

PS: Dont forget to add IHttpContextAccessor registration

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: My question is'nt how to configure session, it is about how to get session when i have session id.

Comment: How am I or anyone supposed to understand this from `i'm trying to get session by .AspNetCore.Session`

Comment: you forgate `cookie`